# Collision Detection for Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection

Well, I was searching for a simple collision detection function for as3, I found Collision Detection Kit, but it is too complicated, I just want a damn function that I give 2 objects as paramenters and that's it.

I would like to know where can I find a pixel-perfect collision detection function (The faster, the better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after reaching 6th page on google, I found a perfect solution:

http://anotherearlymorning.com/files/PixelPerfectCollisionDetection.as

Answer (score 0):

What about the hitTest method of the MovieClip class, if you want something simple?

EDIT: in AS3, you have hitTestObject and hitTestPoint.

Comment: I want a pixel perfect function